# Gas Fireplace Pilot Light Line Replacement

Tags: fireplace, natural-gas, pilot-light

I'm replacing the pilot light assembly on a gas fireplace after removing the old line from the valve, there's no indication any thread sealant was used on the original installation.

Is there any situation with gas line connections where you wouldn't use thread sealing tape (yellow)?

Comment: The pilot light assembly might get too hot for Teflon tape. You need directions specific to this situation. There may a specific high temp gas sealant for this application.  Alternatively, it may be that no sealant is needed if there is virtually no leakage through these threads if there is no pressure there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pilot lines in most cases use 1/4" aluminum tubing and their fittings are compression type fittings that use no pipe dope. In some cases flare fittings have been used for the pilot line. Thread sealing tape is only used on the pipe threads of gas fittings and not the actual pilot tubing.